# curl get request brings no js page version

Tags: javascript, php, curl

When I bring www.amazon.com with curl get request I get no js page version.
My request looks like this:

```
$ch = curl_init ($url );
$header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,"; 
$header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5"; 
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
$header[] = "Accept-Encoding: deflate";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Impossible to say for sure, but I'd imagine that they are checking for a User-Agent header, which you aren't sending. Try adding one.

Comment: I think that they transplant a cookie and then check it. I can reproduce this by disabling js in the browser

Comment: It's the `User-agent` try disabling both cookie and js in regular browser you still get scripts in the page

Comment: I tried and I got js-less flavor of the page